# Array Outputting result set with the same amount of rows in a sql database

Tags: python, mysql, arrays

I have a query that reaches into a MySQL database and grabs row data that match the column "cab" which is a variable that is passed on from a previous html page. That variable is `cabwrite`.

SQL's response is working just fine, it queries and matches the column 'cab' with all data point in the rows that match id `cab`.

Once that happens I then remove the data I don't need line identifier and cab.

The output from that is `result_set`.

However when I print the data to verify its what I expect I'm met with the same data for every row I have.

Example data:

Query has 4 matching rows that is finds

This is currently what I'm getting:

```
> data =
> ["(g11,none,tech11)","(g2,none,tech13)","(g3,none,tech15)","(g4,none,tech31)"]
> ["(g11,none,tech11)","(g2,none,tech13)","(g3,none,tech15)","(g4,none,tech31)"]
> ["(g11,none,tech11)","(g2,none,tech13)","(g3,none,tech15)","(g4,none,tech31)"]
> ["(g11,none,tech11)","(g2,none,tech13)","(g3,none,tech15)","(g4,none,tech31)"]
```

Code:

```
cursor = connection1.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM devices WHERE cab=%s " , [cabwrite])
result_set = cursor.fetchall()
data = []
for row in result_set:
    localint = "('%s','%s','%s')" % ( row["localint"], row["devicename"], row["hostname"])
    l = str(localint)
    data.append(l)
print (data)
```

This is what I want it too look like:

```
data = [(g11,none,tech11),(g2,none,tech13),(g3,none,tech15),(g4,none,tech31)]
```

Comment: How u get 4 list

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code you're sharing and the output you're presenting don't match (for one, your print statement only prints `data`, but your example includes `data = `). If you provide the actual output, that may make it easier to see where you're going wrong.

Comment: u want to remove quotes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to variable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396799/convert-string-to-variable-in-python)

Comment: @SmartManoj It's pretty clear that they want four different strings in the list instead of the same string four times.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for @tripleee I can't post the actual data it would be entirely too long. The example data is formatted identically to what I'm getting.

Comment: The code you posted does not seem to produce what you claim it does, though. Please try to refactor this into a [mre].

Comment: (Also, `localint` is already very much a string; copying it and coercing it to a string doesn't do anything useful.)

Comment: @user1051850 I can see you've changed the question, but your "what I'm getting" is not really "what you're getting", since it's not something your code would produce. Can you please provide the actual output of your script (if that's what you're sharing) or the actual command you enter on the CLI and the actual output Python prints, instead of some 'nicer' version of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
["('Gi3/0/13','None','TECH2_HELP')", "('Gi3/0/7','None','TECH2_1507')", "('Gi1/0/11','None','TECH2_1189')", "('Gi3/0/35','None','TECH2_4081')", "('Gi3/0/41','None','TECH2_5625')", "('Gi3/0/25','None','TECH2_4598')", "('Gi3/0/43','None','TECH2_1966')", "('Gi3/0/23','None','TECH2_2573')", "('Gi3/0/19','None','TECH2_1800')", "('Gi3/0/39','None','TECH2_1529')"]
```

Thanks Tripleee did what you recommended and found my issue... legacy FOR clause in my code upstream was causing the issue.